# Automatically attach new records

Tags: java, jooq

Is it possible to attach a default configuration for creating new records instead of manually attaching each time? I saw that while performing a `SELECT` it automatically attaches the record, would be nice if I could skip this step for every new record created.

```java
var address = new AddressRecord();
address.attach(jooq().configuration());
address.setAddress(addressTemplate.getAddress());
address.setState(addressTemplate.getState());
address.setCity(addressTemplate.getCity());
address.setZipcode(addressTemplate.getZipcode());
address.setCountryId(addressTemplate.getCountryId());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of a Java constructor call (`new AddressRecord()`), it is not possible to intercept such a call e.g. in order to attach the resulting object to a `Configuration`.

But you can use `jooq().newRecord(ADDRESS)` instead, which produces an attached record. You can also use `jooq().newRecord(ADDRESS, addressTemplate)` to copy values using the [`DefaultRecordUnmapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordUnmapper.html)